# phpunit xdebug reporting

Tags: reporting, phpunit, xdebug

I am trying to produce an html report of some tests using PHPUnit, Selenium and Xdebug.  I run the test like so:

```
phpunit --coverage-html ./report blah.php
```

But the report generated is somewhat lacking in information and it doesn't seem to coincide with the official documentation [here](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.2/en/code-coverage-analysis.html).

I just get a green bar with "100.00% | 0/0" as the value for the 'Lines' column. I thought perhaps this was normal but I altered my test script to fail deliberately and the report is the same.  I would've assumed it would at least tell me that it failed.

Any ideas why this is happening?

PS: I am using PHPUnit 3.4.8, Xdebug 2.0.5.

Comment: What's the output of the script? Not the report.

Comment: I have the same question. According to some sources, all you have to do is

phpunit --html-coverage ./report testsuite

like this guy got here. That's what we want.

http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/04/08/reporting-code-coverage-with-phpunit-and-xdebug/

Please help us figure out how to get that, since that part doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Code coverage reports tell you the lines of code that your tests covered, independently of whether they failed or not. It is not the same as reporting the tests results.

Answer (score 0):

@peter-lindqvist: Output of script:

```
$ phpunit --coverage-html ./report blah.php
PHPUnit 3.4.8 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.F

Time: 16 seconds, Memory: 5.50Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) blah::testLocation
Current URL: http://some-url

Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-actual_stuff
+expected_stuff

/home/me/..../blah.php:62

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.

Generating code coverage report, this may take a moment.
```